# One thread with multiple worker processes?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm wondering whats the procedure for having one thread and belonging to that thread one worker which has multiple processes. If that doesn't make too much sense hopefully the code below should explain:

// WORKER.H //

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

Public:
    Worker(QObject *parent = nullptr); 

Public Slots:
    void process1(int x); 
    void process2(int y); 
    void process3(int z); 

signals:
    void sendResult(int result); 
}
```

// CONTROLLER.H //

```
class controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    controller(QObject *parent = nullptr); 

signals:
    operate();

public slots:
    void storeResults(const int);

private:
    QThread myThread; 
}
```

// CONTROLLER.CPP // I shall only give the constructor

```
Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
     Worker *worker = new Worker;
     worker->moveToThread(&myThread); 

     //connections
     connect(&myThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);

     connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::process1); 
     connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::process2); 
     connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::process3); 

     connect(worker, &Worker::sendResult, this, &Controller::storeResult); 

     myThread.start(); 
}
```

What I'm hoping to achieve here is a system where the three processes slots in the worker class will receive data from signals from the GUI. these signals will be constantly being received throughout the life of the program. Once a given signal is received, it shall be processed, and the result of the processing will be emitted into the store result slot.

Would this code achieve what I expect or is there something I'm overlooking?

Many Thanks

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what you expect to happen.  Leaving aside for the moment the fact that the signal and slot parameter lists don't match, with the code shown every time the `Controller::operate` signal is emitted `Worker` slots `process1`, `process2` and `process3` will be run sequentially on `myThread`.

Comment: @G.M. ah okay, so they run sequentially. What I was aiming for is to have each slot from the worker running in parallel (at all times). Can I ask what the effect would be If I had separate worker classes for each of my processes, and added each worker (worker1, worker2 and worker3) to myThread?

Comment: If you want them to run concurrently than, yes, you need three separate threads.  How you chose to do that is up to you.

Comment: @G.M. If I connect three worker classes to a single Qthread, when I start the thread will they all run concurrently, or will the work function of each worker class be carried out sequentially?

Comment: Sequentially.  As I said, if you want N functions to run concurrently you need N threads.  That's the general requirement -- nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: @G.M. ok thanks for your help.